# mysql is not working in xampp what shall i do?

Tags: xampp

```
2024-01-04 19:05:18 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-01-04 19:05:18 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2024-01-04 19:05:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240104 19:05:18
2024-01-04 19:05:18 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2024-01-04 19:05:18 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

What to do?

I was trying to start `mysql` in `xamp` and 2024-01-04 19:05:18 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

```
2024-01-04 19:05:18 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2024-01-04 19:05:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240104 19:05:18
2024-01-04 19:05:18 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2024-01-04 19:05:18 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

this error came

Comment: Do you get any results from  

    USE mysql;  
    SHOW TABLES LIKE 'plug%';